# Laravel Eloquent model id as string return wrong value in

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-5, eloquent

There is OauthClient model which $client->id does not return correct value in Laravel 5.2.

"lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel": "^5.1" is used that has in migration
$table->string('id', 40)->primary();

However when use $client->id in blade template then I get back "0" . Using dd($client) show correct value in id attribute.

What could be wrong?

Model output from dd()

```
OauthClient {#254 ▼
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:7 [▼
    "id" => "wISw4JmlMQCCrMupjojcuDTK3k4hwtkb"
    "secret" => "nnw3CPTzeQSIfT4KpR0d3XzWIKKoghB3"
    "name" => "http://example.com"
    "package" => "free"
    "user_id" => 2
    "created_at" => "2016-07-19 15:36:28"
    "updated_at" => "2016-07-19 15:36:28"
  ]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

Table structure from "show create table oauth_clients"

```
CREATE TABLE `oauth_clients` (
  `id` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `secret` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `package` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `oauth_clients_id_secret_unique` (`id`,`secret`),
  KEY `oauth_clients_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `oauth_clients_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Can you post the output from `dd($client)`

Comment: It is not typical for an data model to have the `id` attribute in there. Usually all attributes are held within an attributes array and there is a magic `__get` method which gets the appropriate one. We will need to see how your `OauthClient`model looks like.

Comment: Added dd() output and create table syntax

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is because by default the primary key is casted as `int` unless explicitly stated otherwise.

```
(int) "wISw4JmlMQCCrMupjojcuDTK3k4hwtkb" == 0
```

The value still exists as string, but if you use the `$model->id` it will go through magic `__get()` method defined in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class.

I'm not going to argue against using `id` field as string, but if you do and also want to get the string value using $model->id, you'll have to cast it as string in you model definition. There is a protected $casts array you can use for that. Just add the following to your OauthClient model:

```
protected $casts = ['id' => 'string'];
```

This will do the trick and cast the id attribute as string instead of default integer. All though I would reccommend not to use id as string in the first place.

**Update:**

There is also an `$incrementing` property, which you can set to `false` on your models, to tell Laravel you want non-incrementing or non-numeric primary key. Set it on your models like this:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

**Update 2:**

Information about this is now also added to official documentation.
Look for **Primary Keys** section at [Eloquent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent):

> In addition, Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing
>   integer value, which means that by default the primary key will be
>   cast to an int automatically. If you wish to use a non-incrementing or
>   a non-numeric primary key you must set the public $incrementing
>   property on your model to false. If your primary key is not an
>   integer, you should set the protected $keyType property on your model
>   to string.

Comment: Thank you very much. It fixed so many issues when using this library!

Comment: The `casts()` does not seem to affect the way `find()` works. It only acts on the setters and getters. If I do a `find(123)` with both your above solutions in place (Laravel 5.6), it will return a model instance with an id of `123abc` - which to me is a serious security issue that could be exploited. The type casting here is happening on the database (a manual select returns the same *wrong* row). Eloquent needs to be told to explicitly cast the ID to a string when doing a `find()`. I cannot see a way to do this within the model (except maybe overriding `find()`).

Comment: Thanks man,  I should have Googled this 5 hours ago.... Out of curiosity, hi[f]w should we know this without reading the whole Laravel core code?

Comment: @sandman At least on latest Laravel docs, there is a section explaining this. Search for [Primary Keys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) But in general, being a programmer usually means reading a lot of core code ;) There are many projects out there, having minimal or outdated docs, so you have no other way than read the code. However, doing this, is best way to learn and will become your second nature soon enough :)

Answer (score 10):

Setting `public $incrementing = false;` worked for me.

http://www.laravel.io/forum/12-14-2015-id-as-string

Comment: This is the more elegant solution for Laravel 5.4