# How to receive the object itself in update and destroy methods instead of id?

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent

I created a controller for a Restful API with the following command:

```
php artisan make:controller API\PeopleDataController --api -m PeopleData
```

and what it made me is a controller with the following methods:

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\PeopleData  $peopleData
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, PeopleData $peopleData)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\PeopleData  $peopleData
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(PeopleData $peopleData)
{
    //
}
```

Please notice the parameters of the functions.
The routs that I defined also is like this:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
    Route::resource('peopleDatas', 'API\PeopleDataController');
});
```

but when I make a PUT or DELETE request with a URL like this:

```
/api/peopleDatas/1234
```

what I receive in `update` and `destroy` functions is not the object with id 1234 but it is the id itself. On the other hand the signature of the functions that are created with artisan must be something like this:

```
 /**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

Now the question is: How can I get a fetched object from the database instead of id. Obviously type casting from int to a model object is impossible and we need to fetch it from DB first:

```
$peopleData = PeopleData::find($id);
```

It seems I missed something that `Laravel` does not fetch the object automatically and passes the id to my function. How can I fix it?

Comment: plz try `php artisan routes:list` and post the route

Comment: the route it self fired. So the route it self is not the problem, because it calls the correct function. The problem is `Route Model Binding` does not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Actually what I discovered is that `Laravel Route Model Binding` is working based on names and I used `Hungarian naming convention` in my function signature:

```
public function update(Request $oRequest, PeopleData $oPeopleData)
```

while based on what a user mentioned [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-route-model-binding-not-working?page=1) the parameters must have same name as model. So by changing the function signature to its original state like the following:

```
public function update(Request $request, PeopleData $peopleData)
```

then the `Laravel Route Model Binding` works again! For me it was a surprise that a variable's name can effect the functionality while we mentioned the type of the variable in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel there is something called [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding). So when you access a route like:

```
/api/peopleDatas/1234
```

eloquent takes the model not the id. You can check it with something like:

```
public function update(Request $request, PeopleData $peopleData)
{
    return $peopleData->id; // or any other column 
}
```

Comment: It returns `null`. The problem is that binding does not happen.

Comment: just as a hint the id in my model is string and not incremental int.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem by adding the option **parameters**.

```php
Route::resource('peopleDatas', 'API\PeopleDataController',[
    'parameters' => ['peopleDatas' => 'peopleData'],
]);
```

laravel forces you to use certain conventions. When you use tables names with an **underscore** for non pivot-tables, you'll start having problems. The option parameters allows you to fix this problem.

Comment: I tested it. unfortunately was not helpful. It return null also.

Comment: A tiny question did you modify the app/Http/kernel.php ? Or are you using strings as ID's? Try public $incrementing = false;

Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463624/laravel-eloquent-model-id-as-string-return-wrong-value-in

Comment: I found the issue. I modified the function signature and that caused the problem.

Comment: Ok, great ! Yes, you have the be careful with the names you use (as you mentioned above).