# One-to-Many relationship returns all, even unrelated rows from table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-10

I have a problem with relationships in Laravel 10. I have two tables in db: 'pages' and 'elements' between which I've tried to establish One-to-Many relationship, however, when I try to access elements related to given page, it returns all elements from table.

Here are simplified migrations for reference:
pages:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{

    public function up(): void {
        Schema::create('pages', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id');
            $table->primary('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down(): void {
        Schema::dropIfExists('pages');
    }
};
```

elements:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration {

    public function up(): void {
       Schema::create('elements', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id');
            $table->primary('id');
            $table->string('content');
            $table->string('page_id');
            $table->foreign('page_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('pages')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        }); 
    }

    public function down(): void {
        Schema::dropIfExists('elements');
    }
};
```

If I run the migrations and seed the tables, everything works, and is filled as expected.

I've tried to setup One-to-Many (Page-to-Elements) relationship between them, however, when I try to access elements on page (`Page::find('some_id')->elements`), it doesn't return only related rows, but instead all, even unrelated ones, and I don't understand why.

Here are Models:

App\Models\Page.php

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Page extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function elements(): HasMany  {
        return $this->hasMany(Element::class);
    }
}
```

App\Models\Element.php

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Element extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function page(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(Page::class);
    }
}
```

I've also tried giving hasMany method column names of foreign and local keys, but with no success.

Everywhere I look, people, and docs seem to do it the same way. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding this line of code in Page model: `protected $casts = ['id' => 'string'];` thanks to previously answered question at: [stackoverflow.com/questions/38463624/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463624/laravel-eloquent-model-id-as-string-return-wrong-value-in)… The problem was, I didn't know that primary key is casted as integer, while my was stored as string, which caused the problem i was facing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).